# UIAlertController : it does not close in a controlleView that a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4, uialertcontroller

I created a class « Chargement »which allows to display an alert with a loading and to close it.

```
import Foundation
class Chargement {
    var alert : UIAlertController;
    var message : String = NSLocalizedString("PleaseWait", comment:"") ;
    let loadingIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView;
    init(message : String?) {
        if(message != nil){
            self.message = message!;
        }
        self.alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: self.message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        self.loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 4, width: 40, height: 60))

    }
    func showLoading(view : UIViewController){
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func closeLoading(){
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When I use my class "Chargement" in a controllerView without `UICollectionView`, it works for example :

```
class ViewController : UIViewController{
 let loadingView : Chargement = Chargement(message: nil);
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad();
   loadingView.showLoading(view: self);
  }

  @IBAction func btn_Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.loadingView.closeLoading();//it works
    }
}
```

But when I use it in a controllerView with `UICollectionView` the alert display works but  it doesn’t close.

```
class TTwoViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
 let loadingView : Chargement = Chargement(message: nil);
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        loadingView.showLoading(view: self);
        loadingData();
    }
 func loadingData() {
        dataManager().getData(num: 1, completion: {
            (data, messages) in
                   self.loadingView.closeLoading(); //it don't work
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData();
                   //self.loadingView.closeLoading(); //it don't work
                })
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show an activity indicator, you can simplify the whole process by using [NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    let activityData = ActivityData()
    NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.startAnimating(activityData)
    NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.setMessage("Please Wait")
    loadingData();
}

func loadingData() {
    dataManager().getData(num: 1, completion: { (data, messages) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.collectionView.reloadData()
             NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
        }
    })
}
```